# What is it that will differentiate a surah than something else?

Tags: quran, challenge-of-the-quran

The Quran challenges the non-believers in [Chapter Number 2 Verse 23](https://quran.com/2/23) to bring a surah like the Quran. What I cannot understand is that Quran is the truth but an article related to ethics or science or about any knowledge can also be true. How is a surah unique and stands out from any other true literature.

I wonder if the second part of the ayah has the answer to my question.

> وادعوا شهداءكم من دون الله ان كنتم صدقين

Hope i have made my point clear.

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does "The True Furqan" meet the Quran's challenge?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36045/does-the-true-furqan-meet-the-qurans-challenge); I'd like to point out in particular [my own answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/36123/17702) where I describe why I think the "challenge" is ill-defined and not really a challenge, but a taunt. This also explains how the Quran is different: it isn't, the taunt is a matter of rhetoric imbued with plausible deniability, not a genuine invitation to competition with well-defined rules.

Answer (score 1):

The facts in Quran is one type of its miraculous nature, other types are telling the real stories from history and future that Mohammad (PBUH) could never know them by himself, also telling about scientific details that were not known at that time, but the one which is related to your question is the **linguistic challenge**.

Quran was revealed at the golden age of the Arabic language, Arabs mastered the language to a great level, they did not need to study it, it was main part of their culture, they were able to say the poetry on the spot due to the level of fluency they reached, at that time when all people mastered the language, the challenge came to make it clear that the style and the build of Quran chapters or verses cannot be by a human, they had all the time and people but no one was able to provide a similar text.

As it is clear to language experts how linguistically miraculous Quran is, it is not that clear to people who do not speak Arabic or not so fluent as the original Arabs,  but by reading on the subject you can better capture it.

Answer (score 0):

Qur'an is different because of its timeless guidance through stories , admonitions, parables and rational arguments. People reading it become more humble, forget their mundane lives and become thoughtful about afterlife, fearing death but also become hopeful for Allah's mercy.